# How the update/change the value of object in array in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array. which name is dynamicform and this in this array have object

```
const dynamicform =[ {
      id: Math.round(Math.random() * 36 ** 12).toString(36),
      mainlabel: checklistlabel,
      type: inputtype,
      grid: inputgrid,
      CheckLists: [
        {
          type: 'checkbox',
          label: "Label one",
        },
      ],
    },
{
   id:id: Math.round(Math.random() * 36 ** 12).toString(36),
   name:"john",
   type:"text"
}]
```

I just want to push a new object in CheckLists Array so, I write this

```
  setDyanmicForm([
        ...dynamicform,
    dynamicform.map((form, idx) =>
      form.CheckLists.push({
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: defualtchecklabel,
      })
    )
     ]);
```

But is showing an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: You need some unique identifier to track in which object you need to update value. Your id is not unique what field is unique in this?

Answer (score 0):

The above error occured because of the second element present inside dynamicForm. See, there is no ***CheckLists*** property present inside that element.

Either you could add a check for **CheckLists** existence or you could do the below thing if you have to push that element for every item.

```
form.CheckLists = form.CheckLists || [];
```

Add this before pushing element inside checklists.

**Note:** You are not destructuring your result from map. Destructure it properly or you'll get an array as element inside setDyanmicForm.